# Using Code In Fulcrum to auto populate a child field with a value from a parent field

Tags: field-calculator

I am unsure if anyone on here uses Fulcrum to collect map data but I imagine code is the same or similar.

I have an app I am creating with a parent form that contains FeatureID and X and Y Co-ords. I then have a repeatable child form to survey this feature a number of times, However when you export the data in csv. it creates two separate files; one for the parent and one for the child, where the child form does not have the Feature ID or coordinates on them.

Within the repeatable form I would like to create fields for the Feature ID, X, and Y that auto populates from the parent fields, What code do I use for this?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out works as putting $ and then the name of the field you want the data to come from